# Keras Network Using Scikit-Learn Pipeline Resulting in ValueError

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I'm working to build a neural network using Keras and the Scikit-Learn Pipeline for pre-processing. So far, I was able to build the pipeline and initial model architecture (very basic), but have had an issue incorporating the two. I was able to use the pipeline for other machine learning models (the issue has been for deep learning).

I continue to receive the below value error:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_53 is incompatible with the
> layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 5 but received
> input with shape (None, 49)

When I update the input_dim of my model to account for the initial error, I receive a similar error after the first epoch has finished running:

> Epoch 1/100 283/300 [===========================>..] - ETA: 0s - loss:
> 0.5751 - binary_accuracy: 0.7925
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 # Fit Model
> ----> 2 history = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_54 is incompatible with the
> layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 49 but received
> input with shape (None, 5)

**What is the best way to go about embedding a keras neural network into an sklearn pipeline (one that requires one-hot encoding categorical variables?**

*Summary of code below:*

```
# Preprocessing Pipeline
numeric_features = list(X.select_dtypes(include=['number']))
numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='median')),
    ('normalize', MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1)))])

categorical_features = list(X.select_dtypes(include=['category']))
categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
    ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', numeric_transformer, numeric_features),
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features)]
)

# Split Data into Training and Test Sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

# Split Training Data into Training and Validation Sets
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.25, random_state=42, shuffle=True)

def CreateModel():
    # Define Model
    model = Sequential([
        layers.Dense(units=32, activation='relu', input_dim=X.shape[-1]),
        
        layers.Dense(units=16, activation='relu'),
        
        layers.Dense(units=1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

    # Specify Optimizer
    optimizer = optimizers.Adam(epsilon=0.01)

    # Compile the Model
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

    return model

# Add Early Stopping
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, min_delta=0.001, restore_best_weights=True)

# Instantiate Baseline Classification Models
clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=CreateModel, verbose=1, epochs=100, batch_size=16, validation_data=(X_val, y_val), callbacks=[early_stopping])

# Fit to the training set
pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('classifier', clf)
])

# Fit Model
history = pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: To my knowledge, this doesn't have a perfect solution.  A couple of options are at https://stackoverflow.com/q/59755378/10495893

Answer (score 0):

There is a issue with your input shape obviously.

You are passing a data with 49 features while you have specified in your first layers input features as X.shape[-1] (input_dim=X.shape[-1]). Change input dim to input_dim=49 or `input_dim=X_train.shape[-1]`.